# How much soil is needed for turf to survive?

Tags: soil, lawn

Our garden currently has a small gravel border all the way around.
When removed it leaves a few inches before it reaches the foundations for the wall.

If we were to turf the lawn, after filling the border with soil, would the turf grow in such a short depth?

I suppose what i am asking is can turf survive with just a few inches of soil beneath it.

Answer (score 5):

You use the word "survive". I have seen grass grow on solid clay.  It looked fine until the dry times in summer when in went brown fast. If all you want is survival a few inches of soil will do.  It will brown out in hot times and then thin out and weeds will get a hold.  This is due to the roots being unable to get enough moisture.

If you want grass to do well and out compete weed seeds then six inches ( ~12 cm) will provide a good chance of success.  If you are ambitious then 12 inches or ~30 cm of soil will really give you nice looking grass.